# IP auto changed on Win2k8 VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, ntp

I'm having a problem with my Win2k8 virtual machine.

After the virtual machine boot, it gets an IP address from DHCP. But later on, NTP makes a big time shift, so Windows automatically renew (in fact I'm not sure if this is true) IP, and it gets a different IP. That makes big trouble to me because IP changes.

Is there a way to prevent Win2k8 to renew IP upon big time shift?

Comment: Have you thought about static IP's? IP Reservation in DHCP?

Comment: Or resolving the underlying issue of the Time make a big shift in the first place?

Comment: Normally, a DHCP client will keep the same IP address when it renews with the DHCP server. Why isn't that happening for your server? For example, my laptop uses DHCP and it's kept the same IP address for years.

Comment: You say you are using Virtual machines and NTP. Note that a standard VM practice is to disable NTP on the virtual machine, since the 'hardware clock' is managed and synchronized by the virtual host and isn't subject to clock drift.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got your information, but big changes in NTP, or time shift changes between a host and the authoritative time server on a network (Typically the server holding the PDC role) do not make a server renew its IP.  Server's, generally speaking, almost always should have a static IP.  There are too many reasons to name, but a few are:

1. Resources that users access regularly could become unavailable at an IP change
2. Other dependancies or other servers that depend on this particular machine might become unresponsive if the intended resources constantly changes.
3. Etc.

Now, about your time being off problem.  Do this:

[Sync with a domain controller](http://stevehardie.com/2011/07/how-to-synchronise-your-clock-with-the-domain-controller/)

**The very first thing I'd do though, is set a static IP on your server.**

## **EDIT**

I misunderstood you the first time around about the NTP issue, and what you are meaning is that the DHCP lease expired as the NTP and the server time got off by so much that the server thought it's lease expired.  Is that correct?  IF so, then it most definitely  is an issue with the time sync and my link will help you.  Let me know.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Time jump makes DHCP service thought lease expires, then Win2K8 redo DHCP Disc process.

Comment: And unfortunately, the Win2k8 is only a part of a testbed, it's not in a domain.

Comment: The fact that it's not in the domain isn't a problem.  You can tell it to sync with an outside time source.  Follow this:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e45ca79c-8f30-4a2f-9c37-4f9925e01e90/how-to-sync-server-2008-r2-with-a-external-ntp-server-local-ntp-ip-address-?forum=winserverManagement

Answer (score 0):

If it's a server then you should be assigning it a static ip address.

Trouble resolved.

Comment: No, this is not the answer I wanted to get. And it's not related to the question.

Comment: @EvanLi : I understand you want to stop the IP shifting after the NTP update, but understand that using DHCP for servers is not a common practice. DHCP tends to be less reliable then static IPs. As you say in your question, "That makes big trouble to me because IP changes." A good way to prevent this is using a static IP. Consider it a best practice.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski As I mentioned, my Win2K8 is just a virtual machine, it lasts only a few hours. It's just a part of a testbed. Everyday we deploy thousands of such testbeds, so hard to use static IP.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @EvanLi , that makes sense. It might help if you emphasize that a bit more in your question.